# Power BI: Count the number of times a value appears in another table

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

I have 2 tables, one of which includes a column of id numbers. The other table has a column with multiple occurrences of each id-number. I would like to add a column to the first table telling me how many times each id appears in the second table.

Power Bi is new to me so I have gotten nowhere so far.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you have relationship between these two table on this ID then you can use simple **measure**:

```
CountOF = CALCULATE(countrows(detail))
```

[image]
[image]